# Is there a way to speed up my code which copy a heavily formula infested worksheet and creates a multiple new sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

My vba code copies 1 hidden tab and creates a number of new sheets on that basis with a different name (name is specified by the user in a section of the excel workbook). The problem is that the hidden tab (that one which is copied) has got a significant number of formulas (about 100 rows x10 columns - most formulas a lookups/vlookups). It means creation of each new sheet take a lot of time - about 25 second each. I need to have calculation on as the results of formulas in each new tab are required for a further processing.

The users i built it for complained that it is long time.

How can i speed up my vba procedure (i can add that i already use Application. property with a various actions switched off - as per below example)?
OR is there no chance to improve speed if you worksheets are so heavily formula infested.

Code :

```
 Sub ConvertInput() ' wrzuc input od uzytkownika z named range w tablice
    Dim i As Integer
    
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.StatusBar = False
  

  If wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Or wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
  wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetVisible
  End If
  

    myArray = Range("rng_Target").Value
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    
            If IsEmpty(myArray(i, 1)) = False Then   'sprawdz czy element of myarray jest pusty czy jest tam jakas wartosc (string)
                
                  wsToDuplicate.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                  With ActiveSheet
                  .name = myArray(i, 1)
                  End With
                  
            End If
                 '================Ten fragment tylko do testu czy array dziala================
                   'MsgBox myArray(i, 1)
                   'Debug.Print myArray(i, 1)
                 '============================================================================
    Next i
    
    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Erase myArray() ' wyczysc array
    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Calculate
    
 If wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetVisible Or wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
 wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 End If
    



Call X
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.StatusBar = True

  

End Sub


    Sub X()

Dim LastRemR As Integer

 For Each wrksh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 
   LastRemR = 119
    
    If wrksh.name <> "TB" And wrksh.name <> "Lead - TO DELETE" And wrksh.name <> "Lead list & MAT" And wrksh.name <> "Input" Then
    
        wrksh.Activate
    
        With wrksh.Range("M20:M119")
        
        .Value = .Value
        
        End With
       
        With wrksh.Columns("M").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        LastR = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row + 1
        End With
        
        
        Rows(LastR & ":" & LastRemR).Delete
        
On Error GoTo Correct:
        
        'Ponownie sprawdz ostatni row aby wsunac borders do ostatniej komorki tabelki
        With wrksh.Columns("M").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        LastR = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
        End With
        
      GoTo Borders:
      
Correct:

        LastR = 20
        
Borders:
        wrksh.Range("B" & LastR & ":" & "L" & LastR).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    
    End If
    
    Next wrksh


End Sub
```

I want to add that i already tried with switching on `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` at the end of the code but the results were pretty much identical as putting 'Calculate' in the middle as it is now.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, `wsToDuplicate.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)`  is the line that is executing really slowly in your code, correct?

Comment: Hi @DecimalTurn, and thanks for you question. No, not really , the problem really starts when code goes to [Calculate] or <code>Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic<code> if i switch it on (currently off as <Calculate>is on , which works slightly faster than <'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic> on at the end.

Comment: Based on your response, I would say that your problem isn't with VBA, it's with Excel calculations. Even after the code ran, if you try to recalculate the workbook [via the ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKm8H.png), does it still take a long time?

Comment: Also, in your question, you wrote "It means creation of each new sheet take a lot of time - about 25 second each" which seems to contradict your previous comment. Can you clarify (ideally by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77848616/edit))?

Comment: I don't think there is a contradiction in my description. I have clearly stated that : *I need to have calculation on as the results of formulas in each new tab are required for a further processing.* This means the creation of each new sheet is not limited to just copying the hidden tab , it also includes calculation of the formulas. I thought it was quite clear but apologies if it wasn't. Creating those tabs with *calculation* method set to manual (as per your question earlier regarding the ribbon)  takes only a fraction of a second however that's not what I am after.

Comment: The `Calculate` is outside of the loop in your code, so it seems to me that you are doing the recalculation only one time (not once per sheet) after all the sheets were copied. It's the right approach to minimize the time spent recalculating.